# C: Comparing two long integers (very strange)

Tags: c, comparison, integer

I have following situation (unix) :

```
x is a long and has value 300
y is a long and has value 50000

if (x <= y) printf("Correct.");
if (x > y) printf("Ouch.");
```

Now I always get "Ouch". That means the program keeps telling me that 300 is greater than 50000!

It only works again when I do

```
if ((int)x <=(int) y) printf("Correct.");
if ((int)x > (int)y) printf("Ouch.");
```

So what is wrong with the comparison operators?

Comment: How is x and y declared and assigned?

Comment: Also printf("%ld %ld", x, y) so you can see the values.

Comment: It may well be that your "long" here is only a 2-byte value, and thus overflowing and coming out negative; sizeof(long) is platform-dependent, so you can't assume it to be what you expect, particularly if you're targeting an embedded platform or somesuch.

Comment: From the fragment, we have to take your word for it that x and y are the types and values you say, and that no other code exists that may have corrupted or modified these values.  Occam's razor suggests that at least one of these assumptions is incorrect.  This is what your debugger is for.

Comment: @Charles Duffy: but why would it then work if he cast the values to int?  Unless int is 8-bits?  @Kyle, you could do sizeof() for the variables to see how many bits are in each.  What platform is this on?  As @freespace asked, how are x and y declared and assigned?

Comment: @freespace9: x and y are local variables, they are the result of some simple computations with some function arguments

Comment: @Zan Lynx: I did this. Wow. Really large numbers. Too large. OK, x=q+(...)  . q is read from a file via sscanf("...%ld", &q). Hum.

Comment: @Kyle - provide a standalone reproducer, including platform details; this is not enough information to determine the issue.

Comment: Charles: `long` is guaranteed by the C standard to be able to store at least the values from -2147483647 to 2147483647 - 2 bytes isn't enough for that.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error. It was using sscanf(...%d) instead of sscanf(...%ld). :( 
Thanks @ Zan Lynx for the hint and thanks to all of you!